# How to evaluate a symbol in a lambda function when defining it?

Tags: elisp, backquote

For example,

```
(lambda () (message "%s" x)))
```

But I would like `x` to be evaluated -- the lambda function should always use that value, instead of the current value of `x`. How should I do it?

Preferably lexical-binding is not required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use lexical binding then you will need to use a sexp that *evaluates* to a lambda form (a list) where `x` has been replaced by the value you want (e.g., the value that `x` has at the time the list is created).  Like this:

```
`(lambda () (message "%s" ,x))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using lexical binding (`lexical-binding` is `t`), then you can store the current value of `x` in a closure:

```
(setq lexical-binding t)
(setq x 42)
(setq f (let ((x x)) (lambda () (message "%s" x))))
(setq x 57)
(funcall f)
==> "42"
```

If you're not using lexical binding, then, as Drew suggested, you must perform some sexp surgery using backquote:

```
(setq lexical-binding nil)
(setq x 42)
(setq f `(lambda () (message "%s" ,x)))
(setq x 57)
(funcall f)
==> "42"
```